# Azure Digital Twin forbbitten words in Query

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

When I execute query

```
SELECT Group FROM DIGITALTWINS Sensor JOIN Group RELATED Sensor.contains WHERE Sensor.$dtId='xxx’
```

I'm getting error

```
RestError: SQL query parse failed: SQL Parser Error, Line=1, Position=7, Message=mismatched input 'Group' expecting {AVG, CONTAINS, COUNT, DEVICES_JOBS, DEVICES_MODULES, DEVICES, DIGITALTWINS, RELATIONSHIPS, JOIN, MAX, MIN, RELATED, SUM, TOP, EXACT, DEFAULT, '*', IDENTIFIER}
SQL Parser Error, Line=1, Position=13, Message=mismatched input 'FROM' expecting BY See samples in http://aka.ms/adtv2query for the correct syntax.
```

But when I change “Group” to another word, ex “a” Query succeeded.
I'm getting this same error when I use the word “Order”.
I think this is because this word is used in normal SQL queries, and even if digital twins don't support it, still want to parse it and I got an error.

Where I can find a list of the forbidden words for queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the set of "reserved" keywords in the language:

- ALL
- AND
- AS
- ASC
- AVG
- BY
- COUNT
- DESC
- DEVICES_JOBS
- DEVICES_MODULES
- DEVICES
- ENDS_WITH
- FALSE
- FROM
- GROUP
- IN
- IS_BOOL
- IS_DEFINED
- IS_NULL
- IS_NUMBER
- IS_OBJECT
- IS_PRIMITIVE
- IS_STRING
- MAX
- MIN
- NOT
- NOT_IN
- NULL
- OR
- ORDER
- SELECT
- STARTS_WITH
- SUM
- TOP
- TRUE
- WHERE
- IS_OF_MODEL

These words cannot be used as identifiers without enslosing them with [[ ]].

[UPDATE] See more details in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/reference-query-reserved

Answer (score 3):

I see that you have mixed single quotes: **'** vs **’** (I am not sure how they are named). Sometimes it happens when copying and pasting text.

Update:
`Group` word (as well as any other reserved word) has to be escaped using square brackets: `[[<IDENTIFIER>]]`.

Query:

```
SELECT [[Group]] FROM DIGITALTWINS Sensor JOIN [[Group]] RELATED Sensor.contains WHERE Sensor.$dtId='xxx'
```

Comment: I have used '' quotes in the query and I can still reproduce the issue when using the word "Group"

Comment: @asergaz you are right, quotes were not the only issue, updated the answer

Comment: @Petr thanks, escaping words worked for me! I also corrected quotes (I added it when I was posting the query, it had no impact on original query) Do you have a list of forbidden words?